# replacing NA with value from a list Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, iteration, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe with 20 columns. I would like to replace the NA values in selected columns (numerical columns) with their averages.

I have a list of the numerical columns names, and a list of their averages. I have written the below function but I am not sure how to apply it to the Dataframe

```
NumColNames=['MinTemp','MaxTemp','Rainfall','WindGustSpeed',\
             'WindSpeed9am', 'WindSpeed3pm', 'Humidity9am', 'Humidity3pm', 'Pressure9am','Pressure3pm']

avgLst=[12,33,44,21,132,35,22,11,4,55]

def replaceNaNum(df, NumColNames,avgLst):
    #iterate through numerical columns names
    for column in NumColNames:
        #iterate through the aveagres in avgLst
        for avg in avgLst:
            #replace each NA value in every column with the corresponding average 
            df=df.withColumn(column, when(df[column] == 'NA',\
                                                       avg).otherwise(df[column]))
    return df
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` here to bind the column names and corresponding averages, and then extract them from a single loop:

```
for column, avg in zip(NumColNames, avgLst):
    df = df.withColumn(column, when(df[column] == 'NA',\
                                                   avg).otherwise(df[column]))
```